# Using Scala Macro Annotation in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-macros

I am trying to use scala macro annotation to simply print return value from a method. I am using Intellij 2017. Here is the code:

```
class PrintResult extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro PrintResult.impl
}

object PrintResult {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    val result = {
      annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
        case q"$mods def $methodName(...$args): $returnType = { ..$body }" :: Nil => {
          q"""$mods def $methodName(...$args): $returnType =  {
            val res = {..$body}
            println($res)
            res
          }"""
        }
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Annotation @PrintResult can be used only with methods")
      }
    }
    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }
}

@PrintResult
object Test extends App {
    def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
        a+b
    }
}
```

I added this config to sbt:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

I also added SBT Compile to Intellij Run Configuration.

I am getting this error:

```
macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
```

Comment: Try `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)`, for me it made a difference for some case.

Comment: BTW, IntelliJ has nothing to do with it, only what build tool, Scala version and dependencies ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the error message:

> another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it

`object Test` must be in a different subproject or in `src/test/scala` (when `PrintResult` is in `src/main/scala`).